# LibXML2: how do I reverse lookup a XPath expression from a node

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

Using the oXygen XML editor I can right click on an XML node and copy the XPath expression to the clipboard, this expression get's me right back to my node when I come back to it.  Here's an example of an XPath expression I copied:

```
/TSS/Sequences[1]/Sequence[1]/Steps[1]/Step[2]
```

My goal is to write an XML journal for changes and identify where, specifically, the change occured.

How do I do this (*find the XFind function for a specific xmlNodePtr*) in LibXML2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libxml2 function is [`xmlGetNodePath`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetNodePath):

> `xmlChar *    xmlGetNodePath      (const xmlNode * node)`
>
> Build a structure based Path for the given node
>
> `node`:   a node
> `Returns`:    the new path or NULL in case of error. The caller must free the returned string